# Get all elements with custum css attribute in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, attributes

We are working on a mobile crossplatform application and want to be able to set an elements height as a percentage of the screenwidth.

So we have to use javascript for it.

To make it a little bit more maintainable we want to implement a custom css property: wheight. This should be a percentage value, the javascript should calculate the correct value and layout the containers.

Now we are stuck at the beginning:
We need to be a able to select all elements with the wheight css attribute. We would like to do this without traversing the dom in it's whole.

Does anybody know a method on how to do this performance friendly?

Comment: I don't believe CSS is designed to be used in this way, so a performance-friendly solution isn't going to be very straightforward (if one exists at all).

Comment: I'm assuming you mean adding adding style="wheight:50%" to elements. How about a css classname and some other attribute on the html element? like <div class="wheight" data-wheight="50%"> to make the jQuery a little simpler. No matter what though, checking for classnames or attributes or custom css properties, you'll need to walk the whole dom right?

Comment: *"We would like to do this without traversing the dom in it's whole.*" - if these elements can be anywhere in the `DOM`, of course you'll have to traverse all of it. No other go.

Comment: BTW is there a specific reason to use a *custom css property* rather than a `data` attribute?